# What should I do when I'm forced to map a union case that shouldn't exist?

Tags: f#

What should I do when I'm forced to map a union case that shouldn't exist?

**The following filter ensures that only elements matching a specific case are added:**

```
let toAvailable = 
    (fun space -> match space with
                  | Available pos -> true
                  | _             -> false)
```

**I then want to map the filtered result to another type:**

```
let availablePositions = 
    positions |> List.filter toAvailable
              |> List.map (fun space -> match space with
                                        | Available pos -> pos
                                        | Allocated _   -> (-1,-1)) // Should never happen
```

However, I'm still forced to handle a case that I handled in a previous operation. Hence, I already filtered out the "Allocated" cases.

What should I do in this situation?

**Here's the complete function:**

```
let optionsFor piece (positions:Space list) =

    let yDirection = match piece with
                     | Black _ -> -1
                     | Red   _ ->  1

    let sourceX , sourceY = 
        match piece with
        | Black (checker , pos) -> pos
        | Red   (checker , pos) -> pos

    let optionsForPiece = 
        (fun pos -> pos = ((sourceX - 1) , (sourceY + yDirection)) ||
                    pos = ((sourceX + 1) , (sourceY + yDirection)))

    let availablePositions = 
        positions |> List.filter toAvailable
                  |> List.map (fun space -> match space with
                                            | Available pos -> pos
                                            | Allocated _   -> (-1,-1)) // Should never happen

    availablePositions |> List.filter optionsForPiece
```

**Here's my entire domain:**

```
open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit

(* Types *)
type Black = BlackKing | BlackSoldier
type Red =   RedKing   | RedSoldier

type Coordinate = int * int

type Piece =
    | Black of Black * Coordinate
    | Red   of Red   * Coordinate

type Space =
    | Allocated of Piece
    | Available of Coordinate

type Status =
    | BlacksTurn | RedsTurn
    | BlackWins  | RedWins

(* Functions *)
let black coordinate = Allocated (Black (BlackSoldier , coordinate))
let red   coordinate = Allocated (Red   (RedSoldier   , coordinate))

let startGame () =
    [ red (0,0);  red (2,0);  red (4,0);  red (6,0)
      red (1,1);  red (3,1);  red (5,1);  red (7,1)
      red (0,2);  red (2,2);  red (4,2);  red (6,2)

      Available (1,3); Available (3,3); Available (5,3); Available (7,3)
      Available (0,4); Available (2,4); Available (4,4); Available (6,4)

      black (1,5);  black (3,5);  black (5,5);  black (7,5)
      black (0,6);  black (2,6);  black (4,6);  black (6,6)
      black (1,7);  black (3,7);  black (5,7);  black (7,7) ] , BlacksTurn

let toAvailable = 
    (fun space -> match space with
                  | Available pos -> true
                  | _             -> false)

let available (positions:Space list) = positions |> List.filter toAvailable

let optionsFor piece (positions:Space list) =

    let yDirection = match piece with
                     | Black _ -> -1
                     | Red   _ ->  1

    let sourceX , sourceY = 
        match piece with
        | Black (checker , pos) -> pos
        | Red   (checker , pos) -> pos

    let optionsForPiece = 
        (fun pos -> pos = ((sourceX - 1) , (sourceY + yDirection)) ||
                    pos = ((sourceX + 1) , (sourceY + yDirection)))

    let availablePositions = 
        positions |> List.filter toAvailable
                  |> List.map (fun space -> match space with
                                            | Available pos -> pos
                                            | Allocated _   -> (-1,-1)) // Should never happen

    availablePositions |> List.filter optionsForPiece
```

**Here are my tests:**

```
[<Test>]
let ``get avaialable positions for black soldier`` () =
    // Setup
    let piece = Black ( BlackSoldier , (1,5) )

    // Test
    let available = startGame () |> fst
                                 |> available
                                 |> optionsFor piece

    // Verify
    let northWestAvailable = available |> List.exists (fun pos -> pos = (0,4))
    let northEastAvailable = available |> List.exists (fun pos -> pos = (2,4))

    (northWestAvailable && northEastAvailable) |> should equal true

[<Test>]
let ``get avaialable positions for red soldier`` () =
    // Setup
    let piece = Red ( RedSoldier , (0,2) )

    // Test
    startGame () |> fst
                 |> available
                 |> optionsFor piece
                 |> List.exists (fun pos -> pos = (1,3))
                 |> should equal true
```

Comment: As a side note - your code tends to wander off to the right, which makes it a bit more difficult to follow (it is still very clean, though). Maybe consider using linebreaks after `=` to help reduce the indentation of the code that follows, and lining up the pipe operators under the initial argument; I have never seen anyone else write them like that.

Comment: Why don't you just collapse it and return Some(pos) and None. Then use List.choose to get rid of the None.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev I updated the format. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @s952163 Please post this as the answer for credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
type Red =   RedKing   | RedSoldier
type Black = BlackKing | BlackSoldier

type Coordinate = int * int

type Piece =
    | Black of Black * Coordinate
    | Red   of Red   * Coordinate

type Space =
    | Allocated of Piece
    | Available of Coordinate



let x1 = Allocated (Black (BlackKing, (5,5)))
let x2 = Available (10,10)
let x3 = Available  (20,10)

let xs = [x1;x2;x3]
```

**EDIT** per TDD's comment:

```
let xs' = 
    xs 
    |> List.choose (function | Available pos -> Some(pos)
                             | _             -> None)

// val xs' : Coordinate list = [(10, 10); (20, 10)]
```

You can also use `Option.map` if necessary.

Comment: Why the "detour" via `List.map`, instead of using the matching function directly in `List.choose`?

Comment: thank you. let me blame this on the lack of caffeine... I'll edit

Comment: Not related to the answer but when possible handle the cases explicitely (using `Allocated _` here) instead of the wildcard. That way when you refactor/update the code and add new cases compiler will warn you of new unhandled case instead of silently swallowing it

Comment: @Sehnsucht absolutely!